# How can I issue a certificate after I've moved to a new cluster?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, cert-manager

I setup up a prototype cluster in Azure Kubernetes Service to test the ability to configure HTTPS ingress with cert-manager. I was able to make everything work, now I'm ready to setup my production environment.

The problem is I used the sub domain name I needed (sub.domain.com) on the prototype and now I can't seem to make Let's Encrypt give a certificate to the production cluster.

I'm still very new to Kubernetes and I can't seem to find a way to export or move the certificate from one to the other.

**Update:**

It appears that the solution provided below would have worked, but it came down to needing to suspend/turnoff the prototype's virtual machine. Within a couple minutes the production environment picked up the certificate.

Comment: You shouldn't need to move the certificate, if you have updated the dns entries correctly to point at the new cluster you should be able to get a new certificate. More information about your configuration would be useful.

Comment: @Marcus I tried that, I gave it over an hour and I continually received certificate issues from the browser. If I look at my running pods, I have a pod called `cm-acme-http-solver` that has been running since I started the cluster. I'm guessing this is cert-manager trying to get a certificate, but it never seems to go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just do something like:

```
kubectl get secret -o yaml
```

and just copy\paste your certificate secret to a new cluster, or use something like heptio ark to do backup\restore.

ps. I dont know why it wouldn't let you create a new cert, at worst you would need to wait 7 days for your rate limit to refresh.

Comment: I've wondered if it's because both are currently online, but I don't know how the Let's Encrypt servicer works underneath it all. I'll try copying the secret and see where that gets me.

Comment: I tried that and gave it about an hour or so to sort itself out. Unfortunately, it's a micro-service our developers are working with quite a bit so I can't take it down for a long time. I'll try making the change overnight and see if I can resolve it that way. I'm just a little nervous now about copying the secret since there are a lot of work arounds I had to come up with on my way to get the prototype cluster working in the first place.